# Android Dynamic Link need to click two buttons after installation

Tags: android

After clicking the dynamic link, phones open the Google Play Store and start installing our App.

The button on Google Play becomes "Continue" after installation, and clicking it redirects me to Google Play again with the button changed to "Open".
And then I have to click the "Open" button again in order to open our App and bring the information of the dynamic link into our App.

Is clicking two buttons a normal behaviour? Could I enable the dynamic link with one click only? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes after installing the application, you have to open in order use the application.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, thanks for your reply.

However, I mean I need to click "Continue" and then click "Open", which means two buttons in order to open my App.

Do you know if there are any way to skip one of these buttons?